# Set node.js process.env variables under AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to propagate Jenkins-build-specific environment variable(s) into a node.js server so that it's possible to know which build#/git-branch/commit-sha the AWS elastic beanstalk environment is running.

Following various AWS guides I've created a file which contains the environment variable(s). The intention is to have the values in the file replaced during the build process so that they reflect build-specific info:

```
$ cat .ebextensions/env.config
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: BUILD_NUMBER
    value: BUILD_NUMBER_VALUE
```

Problem is that when the node instance fires up on the EBS environment,  `process.env.BUILD_NUMBER` is not set (that is confirmed by a `console.log(process.env)` from within the node server).

Any idea what's missing in this configuration for the environment variable(s) to show under Node's `process.env`?

Notes:

- It appears that the `namespace` is not mandatory. To be on the safe side I tried both with and w/o it, there was no difference

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option for you would be to use the `package.json` to generate the statuses for you. If you run `npm version patch` npm will increment the patch version of your application. It will also tag your git repo with the same version name. If you then run an `eb deploy` elastic beanstalk will create a zip file named after your tag. For example:

1. Current version in package.json === "1.3.2"
2. run `npm version patch`
3. new version in package.json === "1.3.3"
4. eb deploy log:

   > Creating application version archive "v1_3_3".`
   >
   > Uploading store-api/v1_3_3.zip to S3. This may take a while.`

You can then require in the `package.json` in your code:

```
var p = require('./package.json');
console.log(p.version);
```

The result is that you end up with a tag in your repo that links up to a version in your package.json file which then also links up to a .zip file in s3.

[image]

Comment: Our system integrates the deployment with builds created by several Jenkins jobs (some are dedicated to gihthub pull requests). As such, I need to tie a specific build with a Jenkins job and its related env variables. Although clear, simple and elegant this solution will not cut it...

Comment: I understood that this answer was not what the author of the question was expecting, but it is exactly what I was searching for. Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

### Found the problem

I feel rather silly about this, because the problem was that the .ebextensions/env.config file was overwritten during a gulp task in the project. Thus the problem was that the config file was not actually deployed. Once deployed, everything worked like a charm...